# Open Material Datepicker on page load

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-datepicker, bootstrap-material-design

I want to open the bootstrap material `datetimepicker` on page load, how I can do that. I have tried many options like triggering the button page onload. It does open if I manually click on the button. Here is the code I have written:

```
<input type="button" id="date" class="form-control floating-label" placeholder="Date">

<script type="text/javascript";>
    var minDate = new Date();
    var numberOfMinDaysToAdd = 1;
    var maxDate = new Date();
    var numberOfMaxDaysToAdd = 15;
    maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() + numberOfMaxDaysToAdd);  
    $( document ).ready(function(){ 
        $('#date').bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({
        format: 'dddd DD MMMM YYYY - HH:mm',
        minDate : minDate,
        maxDate : maxDate,
    });
        $.material.init();
        $('#date').trigger("click");
    });
</script>
```

I have gone through the documentation part, but nothing helps. The Datepicker URL is [here](https://github.com/T00rk/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker)

Comment: remove the comma after  `maxDate : maxDate` to properly close the object. Did you not get any error in your console?

Comment: I don't know which plugin exactly you're using, but look at their docs. Plugins often have methods to do this programmatically.

Comment: I have removed that, but not working.

Answer (score 3):

The default trigger event seems to be `focus`. So use :

```
$('#date').focus()
```

If it didn't work, also try:

```
$('#date').focus().focus()
```

Comment: `$('#date').focus()` worked for me. codepen : https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/PoNJqvd?editors=1010